# C# WPF / WinForms - Calling async method in WPF / WinForm never finishes

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, asynchronous

When I try to call an async method in my WPF project it never stops and returns anything.

I tried several things like:

1:

```
public wndMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Initialize();
}

private void Initialize()
{
    IList<Docker.DotNet.Models.ContainerListResponse> myContainers = myClient.Containers.ListContainersAsync(new Docker.DotNet.Models.ContainersListParameters() { All = true }).Result;
}
```

2:

```
public wndMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IList<Docker.DotNet.Models.ContainerListResponse> myContainers = myClient.Containers.ListContainersAsync(new Docker.DotNet.Models.ContainersListParameters() { All = true }).Result;
}
```

But nothing happens, when I debug it stops at this method call and nothing happens.

The ironic thing is:

When I put the exact same method call in a C# console application, it's running ... don't know why.

The second ironic thing is:

When I created a C# Windows Forms application and put the code behind the "Application.Run(frmMain)" in the Program.cs it's running too.

---

So what's the matter with my async method call and WPF / Forms?

Comment: Does it ever get past that method and allow the rest of the execution for your WPF application? Sounds like a deadlock.

Comment: It stops at this procedure step and when I look at the memory nothing changes.. when this is the definition of a deadlock - then it is a deadlock! :)

Comment: Why is it even async if you wait for `.Result`?

Comment: @Kevin any feedback on the provided answer?

Comment: I got to fix the deadlock. Currently I don't have the source code but I know that I used the "Task" class, the event "Window_Loaded" is not async but with this way the async method is not running into a deadlock.

Something like this:

    string code = Task.Run(GenerateCodeAsync).Result;

Answer (score 5):

> when I debug it stops at this method call and nothing happens.

`.Result` blocking call is causing a deadlock.

Event handlers allow `async void`. So your second option can be refactored to await a result without blocking the UI thread

```
private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    IList<Docker.DotNet.Models.ContainerListResponse> myContainers = 
        await myClient.Containers.ListContainersAsync(new Docker.DotNet.Models.ContainersListParameters() { All = true });
}
```

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)